# The type or namespace name ‘player’ could not be found. (Are you missing a directive or an assembly reference)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a player script in unity to display it’s health and power-level. Though I am getting the desired output but can someone explain what the above problem is about. here is the code:-

```
int health = 100;
int power = 0;
string name = Console.Readline("Hey player!! please type in your name. (Kindly do not use your real name)");


public Player()
{
    Debug.Log("health is " + health);
    Debug.Log("power level is " + power);
    Debug.Log("the name of the player is " + name);

}
```

and the function is here:-

```
Player Warrior = new Player();
```

is it really a serious matter that needs to have a look. I have tried calling the function in some other ways too but this only fits my desire. I have tried to find something on google but can’t find an accurate answer

Comment: Is this the entire code? I mean is this inside a `public class Player { ... }`? Also for Unity specific .. you do not want to have `Console.ReadLine` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have scripted is a constructor:

```
public Player()
{
    Debug.Log("health is " + health);
    Debug.Log("power level is " + power);
    Debug.Log("the name of the player is " + name);

}
```

Constructorts are the only methods you can declare that have no return type (because they are always called with the `new` keyword, and the system returns the new instance for you).

And constructors can only be created in the class that shares the same name as the method itself:

```
public class Player
   {
   public Player()
      {
      ...
      }
   }
```

So, either your constructor is outside the class it relates to, or you have forgotten to add a return type: `void` is not the same thing at all!